# PHP Image Workshop initTextLayer() trims spaces from text

Tags: php

I am using PHP Image Workshop for generating a image with some text on it.
But it trims space in front of text. below is the sample code :

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    $text = '     Text testing';
    $font = 'arial.ttf';

    $baseLayer = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initFromPath('base_image.png');
    $engLayer = PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop::initTextLayer($text,$font, 10,"000000",'0');
    $baseLayer->addLayerOnTop($engLayer, 0, 12, "LT");

    $image = $baseLayer->getResult();
    imagejpeg($image, null, 95);
    ?>
```

[image: output image]

How can i fix this in PHP Image workshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem in PHP Image workshop.

**Why it was happening :**

it was function

> getTextBoxDimension()

in ImageWorkShopLib.php file, while calculating exact bounding box this function does not consider spaces.(it only  consider drawing of our font file)

**Fix to this problem** :

I returned $width calculated from imagettfbbox() function dimensions and $left dimension as required.